# How to wait for the Form submit answer in Selenium?

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, automated-tests, server-side-rendering

I have a Selenium Test and in the test I am clicking on a submit button inside a form like following:

```
WebElement form = someContainerElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("form"));
form.submit():
```

Next I am refreshing the page manually by calling the same url again like following:

```
String url = customFunctionToBuildUrlFromPath("some/custom/page");
webDriver.get(url);
```

By the way, the webDriver is of type `RemoteWebDriver`.
Next I am just testing a few webelements for example if they do exist or not.
Everything works fine locally. On gitlab Pipleine it doesn't. On the pipeline it only works if i add `Thread.sleep(3000)`  it also works on the pipeline.

So I guess I have to wait until the server has processed the post request. Locally it is fast enough but the gitlab Runner is not fast enought.

➡️ So I need to wait until the server sends the answer of the post request or the page is at least refreshed. **How do you wait in Selenium for the answer of a form submit?**

I tried to use WebDriverWait it doesn't seem like there is something like `WebDriverWait.until(PageRefresh)`

Comment: Does this only happen with firefox?

Comment: well I am using Testcontainers and the getWebDriver Method of the BrowserWebDriverContainer class. So I guess It takes Chrome if I understand it right.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a feature selenium tries but can not offer as it is very depended on the actual implementation of the site. [As issue was made](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4570) that has very promising solutions for you. Personally i would try the solution of jimevans first

Comment: Do you mean this "If it's that big a deal, wait for the element you're calling submit() on to become stale (which guarantees the page reload has started), then fall into your "wait for page load" routine." ?

Comment: What is meant by wait to become stale ? How do I do that?